# Modifying headers and footers of a double-sided document with Koma-script "srcbook"

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, double-sided, scrbook

I am writing my thesis, I am using the KOMA-class `scrbook` but I got stuck while changing the style of the document.

First, I have a problem with the headers and footers. The format that I want should look like this for even and odd pages, respectively.

[image: I want the name of the chapter at the right and the page number at the right for even pages]

[image: I want the name of the section at the left and the page number at the left for odd pages]

The preamble of my document is the following

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,headsepline,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
```

But this gives me the following format
[image]
[image]

Note that the chapter and the section name appear opposite to the desired place and also the page number appears in the footer. Does anyone know a way to obtain the format I am looking for? Also, I would like to get rid of the "Chapter 2" I just want the name of the chapter in the header.

Second, since I am using a double-sided format there is a blank page after each chapter. I would like to keep those blank sheets after the title page, the acknowledgments, the abstract, and the table of contents but I do not want it in the rest of the document. Is it possible to do that?

EDIT: This is code gives something with the same format as my current document

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,headsepline,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Abstract}
\lipsum[4-5]
\mainmatter
\chapter{ Cha 2}
\lipsum[6-15]
\section{section 1}
\lipsum[16-22]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alberto, please post a complete, compilable document -- a "minimal working example" -- [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). The `koma-script` documentation explains all your questions. Look at pages 112 and 237.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the page number should be in outer header on `plain` pages (eg. chapter pages) too, you can use:

```latex
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
```

To remove the chapter number from page header use

```latex
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}
```

To remove the blank pages in main matter you can patch `\mainmatter` to set KOMA-Script option `open=any`:

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\mainmatter}{\KOMAoptions{open=any}}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  %twoside,% default
  12pt,headsepline,chapterprefix=true
]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% only needed for outdated TeX distributions
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{mathtools}% loads amsmath
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}% removes chapter number from page header

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\mainmatter}{\KOMAoptions{open=any}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{Abstract}
\lipsum[4-5]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Cha 1}
\lipsum[6-15]
\section{section 1}
\lipsum[16-22]
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[23-50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I have shorten

```latex
\automark{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
```

to

```latex
\automark[section]{chapter}
```

But maybe you want

```latex
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
```